# Usar variable ubicada en el controlador de angularjs en el html!

Tags: html, angularjs, controller

tengo la siguiente duda estoy recibiendo datos de la siguiente manera:

```
    var Getcola= JSON.stringify(response.data);

    localStorage.setItem("GetMycola", Getcola);

     var cola1= localStorage.getItem("GetMycola");

     var Mycola = JSON.parse(cola1);
```

como ven son json y los guardo dentro de una variable para despues usarlos  así:

```
Mycola.rut
```

retornando: 18.334.655-5 (ej.)

el problema que este código esta configurado en el controller que hace la petición y pregunto ¿como uso variable para mostrar el resultado en el html? saludos.

Comment: No te entiendo del todo. ¿Por qué simplemente no `$scope.cola = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('GetMyCola'));`?

Comment: las otras variables son para parsear y despúes se me ocurrio guardar la variable Mycola en $scope y funciono y me di cuenta que el problema es otro... saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar el resultado de las variables deben de estar en el $scope de tu controller. Debes declararla en el controller así:

```
$scope.Mycola = JSON.parse(cola1);
```

Después en el html debes escribir tu variable entre "{{}}". De esta forma:

```
<p>{{Mycola.rut}}</p>
```

Asegurate de que el html está controlado por tu controller con la directiva **ng-controller.**

```
<body ng-controller="myController">

</body>
```